# Update conditional variable in a class when original attribute variable is changed outside of the class

Tags: python-3.x, class, conditional-statements

I'm learning Python, and playing around with creating objects using a class. I have a simple dog class that contains a conditional statement that turns the dog's age into 'dog years' The problem is, if I change the dogs age once the object is instantiated it does not call the class, and therefore doesn't run through the conditional statement again. Should I keep all functions that might need updates outside of a class?

My code is

```
class Dog:

species = "Mammal"            # class attribute - this attribute is set for all objects, a default value.
legs = 4
fur = True
tail = True

def __init__(self,name,age,toy,markings):  # initializer that constructs a new oblect (instantiate)
    self.name = name          #  instance attributes take the value of name passed in
    self.age = age            #  and assigns them to the class to the variables self.name and self.age
    self.toy = toy
    self.markings = markings
    
    if self.age > 2:
        self.dogage = (((age-2)*5)+15+9)
    elif self.age == 2:
        self.dogage = 15+9
    else: 
        self.dogage = 15


fido = Dog("Fido", 6, "Mr Squeeky","black spots, white fur")
Pluto = Dog("Pluto", 10, "Frisbee", "black with white spot forehead")

print("{} is {} years old and is {} years old in terms of dog years".format(fido.name, fido.age, fido.dogage))
print("{} is {} years old and is {} years old in terms of dog years".format(Pluto.name, Pluto.age, Pluto.dogage))

# one year later...
fido.age = 7  # updates the current object witht he new data (age of the dog)
Pluto.age = 11 # updates the current object witht he new data (age of the dog)

print("One Year Later...")
print("{} is {} years old and is {} years old in terms of dog years".format(fido.name, fido.age, fido.dogage))
print("{} is {} years old and is {} years old in terms of dog years".format(Pluto.name, Pluto.age, Pluto.dogage))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__` is called only once during the time of object creation. So, the value of `dogage` doesn't change when you change the value of `age` after object creation. To get the desired output, we can use `setter` and `getter`. So, I would suggest to use `property` decorator.

```py
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.dogage = None
        self.age = age
    
    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age
    
    @age.setter
    def age(self, age):
        if age > 2:
            self.dogage = ((age - 2) * 5) + 24
        elif age == 2:
            self.dogage = 24
        else: 
            self.dogage = 15
        
        self._age = age
```

Output:

```py
>>> dog = Dog('Python', 2)

>>> print(dog.age)
>>> 2
>>> print(dog.dogage)
>>> 24

>>> dog.age = 5
>>> print(dog.age)
>>> 5
>>> print(dog.dogage)
>>> 39
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. I added another method to my code ( I called it birthday ) added a year to the age attribute, and then added the conditional statement

Hope this helps other newbies

```
def birthday(self):
    self.age +=1
    if self.age > 2:
        self.dogage = (((self.age-2)*5)+15+9)
    elif self.age == 2:
        self.dogage = 15+9
    else: 
        self.dogage = 15
```